# Button Array seems to not be working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an exercise that I had to do for my class and was not sure why my button array does not work. The number of times I click the button does not equal to the exact number of times being clicked if that makes sense.

```
function changeDisplay(buttonClicked) {
    if (currentButton == buttonClicked) {
      return;
    }
    if (buttonClicked == "linear") {
      buttonArray[0] = buttonArray[0] + 1;
      document.getElementById('linear').innerHTML = " Linear = " + buttonArray[0];
      document.getElementById('section1').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section1').style.width = "100%";
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section2').style.float = 'none';

      currentButton = buttonClicked;
      console.log("linear " + buttonArray[0]);
    } else if (buttonClicked == "right") {
      buttonArray[0] += 1;
      document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = " Right Sidebar = " + buttonArray[0];
      document.getElementById('section1').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section1').style.width = "100%";
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.float = 'right';
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = "25%";
      document.getElementById('section2').style.float = 'none';
      currentButton = buttonClicked;
      console.log("right " + buttonArray[1]);
    } else if (buttonClicked == "center") {
      buttonArray[0] += 1;
      document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = " Center Sidebar = " + buttonArray[0];
      document.getElementById('section1').style.float = 'left';
      document.getElementById('section1').style.width = "30%";
      document.getElementById('section1').style.marginRight = "25px";
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.float = 'left';
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = "25%";
      document.getElementById('section2').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section2').style.width = "100%";
      currentButton = buttonClicked;
      console.log("center " + buttonArray[2]);
    } else if (buttonClicked == "left") {
      buttonArray[0] += 1;
      document.getElementById('left').innerHTML = " Left Sidebar = " + buttonArray[0];
      document.getElementById('section1').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section1').style.width = "100%";
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.float = 'left';
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.width = "25%";
      document.getElementById('section2').style.float = 'none';
      document.getElementById('section2').style.width = "100%";
      currentButton = buttonClicked;
      console.log("left " + buttonArray[3]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like each section gets an `innerHTML` of `... + buttonArray[0];`, which only refers to the first `"linear"` button, is that intentional?

Comment: Why not just attach different Events to different buttons. Seems like a bad practice, unless you can explain otherwise.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yeah that is not intentional. Would it work if I did buttonArray[0], buttonArray[1], buttonArray[2], buttonArray[3]?

Comment: @PHPglue that would actually make more sense